# Datatables and json escaping

Tags: json, datatables

i have json with \ escape (as seen in chrome inspector):

"[{\"Id\":3,\"Email\".....

When i try to populate jQuery Datatables i get the following error:

```
Requested unknown parameter 'Id' for row 0
```

In my javascript:

```
table = $('#UserTableList').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/User/GetUsers',
        dataSrc: ''
    },

    columns: [
        { data: 'Id' },
        { data: 'Email' }]
});
```

The problem is the \ escape in the json?

Comment: Please show a full example of the returned "JSON".  You obviously also have a problem with the serverside script, you could post that too.

Comment: Correct the code on the server to produce valid response in JSON format. You can always use http://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON.

Comment: That's what chrome inspector indicates, your json doesn't have those "\". see the raw data.